# BMP изображение в массив

Tags: массивы, qt, qtcreator

Как в Qt можно перевести изображение 256х256 в двумерный массив?

Answer (score 1):

Загружаете изображение в QImage через QImageReader, потом используете QImage::pixel для чтения пикселов в изображении. А там уже как нибудь по массиву и раскидаете. Почитайте полностью документацию по QImage.

Comment: А чтобы не копировать по одному символу есть QImage::scanLine() и QImage::bits(), которые возвращают указатель на сырые попиксельные данные...